# Статические анализаторы C/C++

Tags: c++, c, статический-анализ

BLAST, CODAN, cppcheck, slint, clang, что-то ещё?

Интересуют:

1. бесплатные и
2. Linux.

До сих пор имел дело только с CODAN (в Eclipse CDT из коробки) и cppcheck. По метке смотрел, но интересует именно безопасность и "корявость" кода, в идеале - что-то приближенное к MISRA.

---

> CLion с его прекраснейшим парсером

Я не прошу IDE. Анализатор для меня ценен как утилита, которая *может* встраиваться в IDE (тогда это бонус), но *обязана* работать самостоятельно.

Что касается прекрасности парсера в CLion. Да, на тестовом прогоне он нашёл несколько плюшек:

1. **Data flow analysis**: File is too complex to perform context-sensitive data-flow analysis (at line 11) (*хи-хи*)
2. **Type checks**: Parameter type mismatch: Values of type 'size_t' may not fit into the receiver type 'int' at line 267 (*второй аргумент fgets()*)
3. **Unused code**: Unused import statement at line 9  (*речь шла о включении ненужного* `.h`)

Вроде бы полезно. Но он **не нашёл главного**:

```
cppcheck: (error) Memory leak: src (at line 249)
```

Тут я специально закомментировал вызов `free()`, причём не прямой, а через враппер(!), что cppcheck прекрасно отловил. CODAN тоже справился. А CLion - нет. Так что до прекрасности ему ещё очень далеко. Не говоря уж о полном отсутствии нормальной поддержки valgrind (ох, не свалиться бы в холивар про IDE...)

> Не то, чтобы отдельный анализатор, но clang на максимальном уровне варнингов довольно полезная штука

Примеры можно? Я с ним дел не имел, и пока не очень представляю, в чём отличие от этого:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -pedantic-errors
```

Comment: почему только бесплатные интересуют?

Comment: По-моему это очевидно. Ну не готов я выложить 400 баксов за ту же single-user лицензию на PC-Lint. И это при том, что он самый дешёвый из всех. Впрочем, если продемонстрируют, что оно, или Klockwork какой-нибудь, на голову выше бесплатных - можно будет и подумать.

Comment: CLion  с его прекраснейшим парсером (лучшие парсеры на рынке сейчас у JetBrains) стоит 200 баксов. Если вы зарплату получаете за плюсы, то берите лучшие инструменты доступные.

Comment: @strangeqargo в Clion есть *статический* анализатор кода?

Comment: @gecube https://twitter.com/clion_ide/status/646794937153904641 https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.1/code-analysis.html?origin=old_help

Comment: @strangeqargo, меня интересуют *статические анализаторы*, а не IDE и их парсеры. Именно как отдельные утилиты, а не привязка к конкретному окружению/IDE. На CLion, кстати, как и на все продукты JetBrains, у меня есть тичерская полная лицензия. Не прокатило, поигрался и забыл.

Comment: @PinkTux ну, возможно, у нас разные рабочие проблемы. У меня большие проекты и быстрая разработка главное в данный момент. Эклипс такого не позволяет, к сожалению. Апвоут, поскольку любые инструменты улучшающие разработку - это важно.

Comment: "*берите лучшие инструменты доступные*" вот я и хочу выяснить что есть лучше. Причём не только плюсы, но с C в обязательном порядке.

Comment: не могу представить себе инструментарий работающий с плюсами без проклятого C

Comment: всё-таки плюсовый и сишный анализаторы - они разные. тот же MISRA плюсы не покрывает вообще, для них другой набор тестов, хоть и похожий. и наоборот, MISRA C++ сишный код анализирует вяло.

Comment: Не то, чтобы отдельный анализатор, но clang на максимальном уровне варнингов довольно полезная штука, даже если проект собирается, например, в студии в итоге.

Comment: оно чем-то отличается от `gcc -Wall -pedantic`? это дефолт у меня.

Comment: Clang'овый `scan-build`? Или под Clang он и имелся в виду?

Comment: Если у вас open-source, то есть возможность получить PVS Studio

Comment: @АлексейЛобанов, у них же с не-Windows до сих пор никак. Да, попытки были, на хабре писали, но...

Answer (score 2):

Сейчас под Линукс появился [PVS-Studio](http://www.viva64.com/ru/pvs-studio-download-linux/), который можно даже [бесплатно полно-функционально использовать](http://www.viva64.com/ru/b/0457/). На самом деле неплохая вещь.

Answer (score 0):

Clang: scan-build tool. Это специальный статический анализатор сей и плюсов.